# Working Android KitKat code crashes on Lollipop devices

Tags: java, android, listview, android-bitmap

I have been working on a social media app which has been running well so far on all devices running on KitKat and lower.

I tried running it on Lollipop and higher os versions and it crashed.

After weeks of debugging, all I have is still an error message which has nothing to do with my code:

```
01-22 00:37:09.481 6661-6672/supernet.interactapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74616433 in tid 6672 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-22 00:37:09.480 6661-6676/supernet.interactapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7891(375KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(64KB) LOS objects, 35% free, 723KB/1117KB, paused 39.238ms total 140.184ms
01-22 00:37:09.501 5229-5290/supernet.interactapp:remote E/Ultra Admin: retrieve messages called: CONNECTED
01-22 00:37:09.571 6661-6676/supernet.interactapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 447(37KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 57% free, 764KB/1788KB, paused 6.993ms total 51.547ms
01-22 00:37:09.588 85-85/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-22 00:37:09.588 85-85/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:5.1/LMY47D/buildbot11172007:userdebug/test-keys'
01-22 00:37:09.588 85-85/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
01-22 00:37:09.588 85-85/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
01-22 00:37:09.588 85-85/? I/DEBUG: pid: 6661, tid: 6672, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> supernet.interactapp <<<
01-22 00:37:09.588 85-85/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x74616433
01-22 00:37:09.651 85-85/? I/DEBUG:     eax 7461642f  ebx f6352bac  ecx 00000001  edx 70612f61
01-22 00:37:09.651 85-85/? I/DEBUG:     esi f3e9ebe0  edi f3e9ebe0
01-22 00:37:09.652 85-85/? I/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000003f  xss 0000002b
01-22 00:37:09.652 85-85/? I/DEBUG:     eip f5fd09fb  ebp 00000000  esp eebff950  flags 00210282
01-22 00:37:09.653 85-85/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 001019fb  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::freePixels()+43)
01-22 00:37:09.653 85-85/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00101a6a  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::~SkBitmap()+26)
01-22 00:37:09.667 85-85/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000e02e3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
01-22 00:37:09.687 85-85/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0001d992  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat
01-22 00:37:09.697 85-85/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 70612f60  <unknown>
01-22 00:37:09.704 85-85/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 892cec82  <unknown>
01-22 00:37:09.740 85-85/? W/libbacktrace: virtual bool Backtrace::VerifyReadWordArgs(uintptr_t, word_t*): invalid pointer 0x74616437
```

I use absolutely no native code in the app.

What could be the cause?

I have tried turning off hardware acceleration in my code and that does not help.
The crash occurs when I am trying to open the contacts list. My contacts list has barely 3 images and they all have sizes in tens of kilobytes.

Finally, this is the code that loads the Bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(File data,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getAbsolutePath(), options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getAbsolutePath(), options);
    }
```

What could cause this crash?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that it looks like the system is running out of memory or something perhaps as a result of something happening in native code?

```
    01-23 10:30:31.561 2106-2121/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark

sweep GC freed 7418(355KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(48KB) LOS objects, 1% free,

 21MB/21MB, paused 7.940ms total 40.757ms
```

**UPDATE**

I ran the application on an Infinix X510 using Android 6.0 MarshMallow and I got the errors:

```
01-23 20:13:12.418 5592-5600/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 5600 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-23 20:13:12.474 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-23 20:13:12.474 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Infinix/Infinix_X510/Infinix_X510_sprout:6.0/MRA58K/1452855576:user/release-keys'
01-23 20:13:12.474 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
01-23 20:13:12.475 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
01-23 20:13:12.475 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG: pid: 5592, tid: 5600, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> supernet.interactapp <<<
01-23 20:13:12.475 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0
01-23 20:13:12.499 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG:     r0 afa193c0  r1 afa193a0  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
01-23 20:13:12.499 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG:     r4 ae67bfe0  r5 00000001  r6 ffffffff  r7 ffffffff
01-23 20:13:12.499 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG:     r8 00000000  r9 ab5de800  sl 00000000  fp 12e69e40
01-23 20:13:12.499 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG:     ip b5c804b4  sp b3c5e528  lr b6e9add7  pc 00000000  cpsr 40070010
01-23 20:13:12.500 5695-5695/? E/AEE/LIBAEE: aee_try_get_word: read:5600 addr:0x00000000 ret:-1, 5
01-23 20:13:12.503 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000  <unknown>
01-23 20:13:12.503 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0008fdd5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::Bitmap::~Bitmap()+20)
01-23 20:13:12.503 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0008fdff  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::Bitmap::detachFromJava()+30)
01-23 20:13:12.503 5695-5695/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 72a75785  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x23a4000)
01-23 20:13:12.808 5695-5695/? E/DEBUG: waitpid failed: tid 5592, No child processes
```

AND

a stacktrace:

```
01-23 20:13:21.458 5699-5699/? D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 0, colorType 4, w 676, h 931, sample 1, bsLength 99cf!!
01-23 20:13:21.459 5699-5699/? D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 0, colorType 4, w 676, h 931, sample 1, bsLength 99cf!!
01-23 20:13:21.459 5699-5699/? D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 1, colorType 4, w 676, h 931, sample 8, bsLength 99cf!!
01-23 20:13:21.543 5699-5699/? D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 0, colorType 4, w 1914, h 1076, sample 1, bsLength 28d55!!
01-23 20:13:21.544 5699-5699/? D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 0, colorType 4, w 1914, h 1076, sample 1, bsLength 28d55!!
01-23 20:13:21.544 5699-5699/? D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 1, colorType 4, w 1914, h 1076, sample 32, bsLength 28d55!!
01-23 20:13:21.605 5699-5699/? D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 0, colorType 4, w 571, h 559, sample 1, bsLength a716!!
01-23 20:13:21.605 5699-5699/? D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 0, colorType 4, w 571, h 559, sample 1, bsLength a716!!
01-23 20:13:21.605 5699-5699/? D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 1, colorType 4, w 571, h 559, sample 8, bsLength a716!!

01-23 20:13:29.093 5699-5708/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
                                                 Process: supernet.interactapp, PID: 5699
                                                 java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.graphics.Bitmap$BitmapFinalizer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeDestructor(Native Method)
                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.-wrap1(Bitmap.java)
                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap$BitmapFinalizer.finalize(Bitmap.java:1667)
                                                     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:212)
                                                     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:191)
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be in the FinalizerDaemon... May not be of much help but do you have some long running `finalize()` method?

Comment: Like where would that be running? I load the contacts json and their images from the file system in an AsyncTask.

Comment: the posted logcat is from genymotion, right?

Comment: Yes @g2o. But I have gotten complaints from real devices Samsung, InJoo etc. running Lollipop and higher, about the crashes too.

Comment: Do you try by yourself on a real device with Lollipop?

Comment: Yes I did..crashed too

Comment: try using a library like Picasso or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and see if it crashes or not?

Comment: Hmmm, to load the files from disk? I am running some tests on it. I will get back to you soon please, @eriuzo

Comment: I used Picasso and it crashed again. signal 11 SIGSEGV code 1 SEGV_MAPERR

Comment: Please check my edits. I tried it on an Infinix device running Android 6.0 and it crashed in native code again, but gave me stacktrace in android's Bitmap code where it happened. It seems to have happened in the nativeDestructor method called in the finalize method of Bitmap's BitmapFinalizer class

Comment: have you tried testing with another image? seems to me either skia or the image that is problematic.

Comment: @eriuzo ... I doubt its the images..because my other users also complained about the same thing on their Lollipop+ devices.

Comment: can you post how do you use picasso? also, how do you create the image files? perhaps the file you created are somehow all corrupted in some way?

Comment: Bitmap map = Picasso.with(context).load("file:"+file.getAbsolutePath()).get();      Something like the above. i will verify it properly once I get on my pc.

Comment: I use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile to store the image's bytes as they come in over volley's ByteArrayRequest.

Comment: I use Picasso like this:                    Bitmap map = Picasso.with(context).load("file:"+file.getAbsolutePath()).resize(50,50).get();

Comment: I followed your cue on image corruption and I found that as the images come in over the network, I save them as byte arrays...not with bitmap.compress. During loading, I read the byte array from the file using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils. Then I use BitmapFactory to decode the byte array as bitmap. Where could the corruption come from?

Answer (score 1):

Do you check the memory of your device, when loading bitmap? I know your're calculating inSampleSize, but i faced the same problem because i was passing wrong values to parameters reqWidth and reqHeight, and of course, inSampleSize was to big and collapse device memory. This problem was in a Photo Gallery.

I hope this help!!

Comment: Thanks for commenting!       
Hmm, I actually do. The size is about 50 x 50. And the same code is used to load images coming from the server on another page of the app..and it works really fine.

Comment: Please check my edits. I tried it on an Infinix device running Android 6.0 and it crashed in native code again, but gave me stacktrace in android's Bitmap code where it happened. It seems to have happened in the nativeDestructor method called in the finalize method of Bitmap's BitmapFinalizer class